# Ruby Quotation Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I wanted to ask this as I looked and it's specific and couldn't find other threads on it.

I want to make a regex that will Capture everything that would lie between two quotations and the quotations as well surrounding.

like:   "insert whatever string here (which can include " "'s)"

basically I want a regex line that would take the quotations AND everything in between them (can be anything).

So a line with quotations and anything that lies inside of it.

I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Sounds slightly problematic.  To clarify what you are asking:  you want the largest string that is surrounded by quotation marks, even if there are quotation marks within the string.  So "foo"mary" should match as foo"mary, correct?

Comment: How about some samples of what you want to match and not match?

Comment: Why a regex? Might be easier to just count them, use a stack, etc.

Comment: "foo"mary" would be that whole statement.

Comment: i hope im not just being stupid. i'm half asleep now.. bleh

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. As @Mori said, please provide examples of what should/shouldn't be matched, including edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just having a problem with the single and double quotes. Use this:

```
%q{like: "insert whatever string here (which can include " "'s)"}[/".*"/]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the regex side of things, you could try this:

```
str = %q{uncaptured " captured " " /captured " /uncaptured}
str[/".*"/]
#=> "" captured " " /captured ""
```

For a non-regex solution, you just find the first and last index and collect the substring in between:

```
str[str.index('"')..str.rindex('"')]
```